# Flutter Firebase Authentication State Management - page only changes after hot restart

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I've been trying to implement 'email and password sign in' and 'google sign in' into my project, and
they're both working fine (I can see the new credentials in the firebase console). The problem is, the authentication pages don't route to the homepage unless I hot restart the project.

here's the main.dart file:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ListenableProvider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
          initialData: null,
        ),
        ListenableProvider<GoogleSignInProvider>(
            create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'DM Sans',
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(), 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User?>();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return HomePage();
    }
    return Menu();
  }
}
```

I didn't include email and google authentication files since they're both working fine.

I'd be grateful if someone could help.

**UPDATE:**
I updated the Wrapper as:

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            User? user = snapshot.data;
            return HomePage();
          }

          return Menu();
        });
  }
}
```

to avoid the problems coming from `context.watch<User?>()` but still having the same issue as before. The `snapshot` doesn't update itself unless I hot restart the project.
Here's the `NotifyListeners()` part to make sure this isn't the problem.

```
Future<String?> signIn(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      notifyListeners();
      return "Signed in";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It hard to explain everything but I point where is mistake `context.watch<User?>()`

Comment: What else can I use to check if the user is null or not?

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your logic into `Consumer` or `Selector` so that the consumer will listen to changes for a given provider, and whenever a change happens in the provider followed by `notifyListeners();` will cause the consumer to rebuild and do its logic again

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<User>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, provider, Widget child) {
        if (/*  check if your provider has a user  */) {
         return HomePage();
        }
      return Menu();
    }); 
  }
}
```